# reduce() to merge if there are blank DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reduce

I want to use `reduce()` function to merge data.

```
final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='KEY',how="outer"), [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8])
```

However, sometimes some dataframe `df1` to `df8` might be blank (but there is at least one dataframe not be blank).
And I do not want to detect which one.

For example, this time `df1` to `df7` are blank and only `df8` is non-blank. Next time `df1`, `df2`, `df5` are non-blank.

How should I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite your function to check for blank dataframes using the property [**`DataFrame.empty`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html):

```
def my_merge(left,right):
    if left.empty: return right
    if right.empty: return left
    return pd.merge(left,right)

final = reduce(my_merge, list_of_dfs)
```

Comment: Dang it! You are too quick ⚡

Comment: I guess we can use something like this using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) -> `reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(...), filter(lambda df: df.empty, dfs_list))`